# How to get all static properties and its values of a class using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I hava a class like this:

```
public class tbl050701_1391_Fields
{
    public static readonly string StateName = "State Name";
    public static readonly string StateCode = "State Code";
    public static readonly string AreaName = "Area Name";
    public static readonly string AreaCode = "Area Code";
    public static readonly string Dore = "Period";
    public static readonly string Year = "Year";
}
```

I want to write some statement that returns a `Dictionary<string, string>` that has these values:

```
Key                            Value
--------------------------------------------
"StateName"                    "State Name"
"StateCode"                    "State Code"
"AreaName"                     "Area Name"
"Dore"                         "Period"
"Year"                         "Year"
```

I have this code for getting one property value:

```
public static string GetValueUsingReflection(object obj, string propertyName)
{
    var field = obj.GetType().GetField(propertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    var fieldValue = field != null ? (string)field.GetValue(null) : string.Empty;
    return fieldValue;
}
```

How I can get all properties and their values?

Comment: Those are static fields, not static properties. Do you want both? Or only fields?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

> how I can get all properties and their values?

Well to start with, you need to distinguish between *fields* and *properties*. It looks like you've got fields here. So you'd want something like:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> GetFieldValues(object obj)
{
    return obj.GetType()
              .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
              .Where(f => f.FieldType == typeof(string))
              .ToDictionary(f => f.Name,
                            f => (string) f.GetValue(null));
}
```

Note: null parameter is necessary for GetValue for this to work since the fields are static and don't belong to an instance of the class.

Comment: I had to use BindingFlags.NonPublic with a `public object MyObject { get; private set; }`

Comment: @jonyfries: Yes, because you don't have any public fields there - you have a public *property*. The code in the question has public fields, as per the first part of my answer. If you want to use properties, call `GetProperties` instead. If you want to access the fields backing automatically implemented properties, you need to specify `BindingFlags.NonPublic` because they'll be private.