# How I can detect that one object of the class has a X value on a variable

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class named `Driver` where there are 20 objects and I would like that when one of the objects class variable is equal to 2 use their variable values. I have like 20 codes like Window code just changing the object of the class, and I would like to do this for making it simple.

```
public class Driver
{
    public float Position;
    public float DriverID;
    public float TeamID;
    public float TyreCompound;
    public float BestLap;
    public static Driver van = new Driver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    public static Driver ric = new Driver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    public static Driver vet = new Driver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    public static Driver rai = new Driver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    public static Driver gro = new Driver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    public static Driver eri = new Driver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    public static Driver per = new Driver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    public static Driver alo = new Driver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    public static Driver str = new Driver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    public static Driver mas = new Driver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    public static Driver mag = new Driver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    public static Driver kvy = new Driver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    public static Driver hul = new Driver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    public static Driver pal = new Driver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    public static Driver oco = new Driver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    public static Driver ves = new Driver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    public static Driver ham = new Driver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    public static Driver sai = new Driver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    public static Driver bot = new Driver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    public static Driver weh = new Driver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    public Driver(float position, float driverid, float teamid, float tyre, float bestlap)
    {
        Position = position;
        DriverID = driverid;
        TeamID = teamid;
        TyreCompound = tyre;
        BestLap = bestlap;
    }

    public void SetData(float position, float driverid, float teamid, float tyre, float bestlap)
    {
        Position = position;
        DriverID = driverid;
        TeamID = teamid;
        TyreCompound = tyre;
        BestLap = bestlap;
    }
}
```

In the window

```
if (App.Driver.van.Position == 2)
{
    TowerSecondName.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/Drivers/driver_" + (App.Driver.van.DriverID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
    TowerSecond.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TeamColours/" + (App.Driver.van.TeamID) + "Opa" + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
    TowerSecondTyre.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TyreIcons/" + (App.Driver.van.TyreCompound) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear...please specify what you want...

Comment: Are you looking for a way to iterate through all the static fields of your `Driver` type, to search for ones of type `Driver` with a specific value?  If so you could start with [How to get all static properties and its values of a class using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12474908/3744182).

Comment: "when one of the objects variable of the class" doesn't make any sense. Please give a concrete example of the case you have in mind. Concrete, specific, definite. If you are unable to communicate what you are trying to do, nobody will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of declaring a lot of individual variables, use a collection, e.g. declare an array

```
public static Driver[] Drivers = new Driver[] {
    new Driver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    new Driver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    new Driver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    ...
    new Driver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    new Driver(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
};
```

Now you can access the drivers by an index or enumerate them

```
foreach (Driver driver in App.Driver.Drivers) {
    if (driver.Position == 2) {
        TowerSecondName.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/Drivers/driver_" + (driver.DriverID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        TowerSecond.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TeamColours/" + (driver.TeamID) + "Opa" + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        TowerSecondTyre.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TyreIcons/" + (driver.TyreCompound) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        break;
    }
}
```

If you know LINQ, you can search for a driver like this instead

```
Driver driver =  App.Driver.Drivers
    .Where(d => d.Position == 2)
    .FirstOrDefault();
if (driver != null) {
    TowerSecondName.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/Drivers/driver_" + (driver.DriverID) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
    TowerSecond.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TeamColours/" + (driver.TeamID) + "Opa" + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
    TowerSecondTyre.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/TyreIcons/" + (driver.TyreCompound) + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Arrays are not the only collection type you can use. You could also use a `List<Driver>`. It has the advantage that it can grow dynamically. A `Dictionary<string, Driver>` has the advantage that you can look up a driver by name (or by any other unique property used as key) very fast. Consider also adding the name of the driver as field or property in the `Driver` class as replacement for the variable names.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of giving all variables a different name, store them in a dictionary. That way you have only one variable which holds all the objects and you can iterate through them, like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var drivers = new Dictionary<string, Driver>();
    drivers.Add("van", new Driver());
    drivers.Add("ric", new Driver());
    // ... etc.

    foreach(var driver in drivers)
    {
        if(driver.Value.Position == 2)
        {
            // Do something
        }

        if(driver.Key == "van")
        {
            // Do something else
        }
    }
}
```

Items in a dictionary are stored in KeyValuePairs and you need to define whether you want to access the key or the value of it, therefore `.Value` and `.Key`.